# Does CLAccuracyAuthorization impact CLCircularRegions or Beacon Regions?

Tags: core-location, clcircularregion

Apple's documentation isn't very clear on this: does anyone know if the delegate callbacks when crossing the boundary of geofenced regions is negatively impacted if the user elects to not share precise location with the app? I'd hope not, but I'm not sure.  I'd especially expect that the bluetooth beacon regions wouldn't be impacted, but again, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It’s buried in their WWDC20 video. Beacons and fences are both disabled.  Booooo!